# Flask: 400 Bad Request when serving template from GET request

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a Python/Flask web application, and I have this code which is giving me an 400 Bad Request error:

```
@app.route('/action/b_book_flight', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def action_b_book_flight():
    return render_template('action.b_book_flight.html', fli_no = request.form["fli_no"])
```

Changing the variable names did not work. Even removing the request.form[] did not work. What am I doing wrong here.

Doing another page does in fact work.

Comment: Just send `request.form`

Comment: `request` is avaiable within jinja by default - [http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-context)

Comment: `return` if all form parts okay otherwise `return` traceback... GET and POST using both, need default_page or random page !